# ruby 'daemonized' script presenting unexpected issues

Tags: ruby, daemons

I have here a script that has suddenly changed behavior and I can't work out why.  As far as I know, no changes to the script have been made and neither have any changes to rubies or gems.

First of all, here is the script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
require 'beanstalk-client' 
require 'sequel'
require 'fileutils'
require 'chronic'

APP_DIR = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
ROOT_DIR = File.expand_path(File.join(APP_DIR,'..', '..'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(APP_DIR)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(ROOT_DIR)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(ROOT_DIR, 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(ROOT_DIR, 'db'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(ROOT_DIR, 'scripts'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(ROOT_DIR, 'models'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(ROOT_DIR, 'systems', 'shared', 'models'))

puts "Starting Daemon..."
Daemons.run_proc(File.join('var', 'background_jobs'), :log_output => true) do

  require 'environment'

  puts "renaming log file..."
  FileUtils.mkdir_p('var')
  begin 
    FileUtils.mv(File.join('var', 'background_jobs.output'), File.join('var', "#{Time.now.to_s.gsub(":","").gsub(" ", '_')}.log"))
  rescue
    # NOP
  end

  SequelOutput.prepare_database(MyDatabase::DB)
  beanstalk = Beanstalk::Pool.new(["0.0.0.0:11300"])
  loop do
    beanstalk_job = beanstalk.reserve 
    begin
      jh = beanstalk_job.ybody
      puts "processing #{jh[:job_id]}"
      job = MyDatabase::DB[:project__jobs].filter(:id => jh[:job_id]).first

      script_name = MyDatabase::DB[:project__available_tasks].filter(:id => job[:script_id]).get(:name)
      task = eval(camelize script_name).new(job)
      puts "processing script: #{script_name} aka (#{camelize script_name}) with #{task.steps} steps"

      task.process
      puts "finished #{jh[:job_id]}"
    rescue
      # NOP 
    end
    beanstalk_job.delete
  end
end
```

The script is called 'run.rb' and has the path /var/www/main/projects/systems/background. This script is called on by two different bash scripts, located in the 'main' folder. The first, called 'background_restart.sh', calls the ruby interpreter and the fully qualified name as follows:

```
cd /var/www/main
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/ruby /var/www/main/projects/systems/background/run.rb stop
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/ruby /var/www/main/projects/systems/background/run.rb start
```

This now fails, outputting 'Terminated' only to the terminal. The other script, called 'deploy.sh', deploys the Webapps, and fails with the same output (its first and last commands are a stop and start respectively).

I have no explanation as to why this has suddenly started to fail.

Some other things to note:

1. Calling the fully qualified path of the script in the terminal works if I am in the background directory.
2. Changing the directory in the bash scripts to 'background' first appears to bandaid the problem, though it is somewhat unsatisfactory to me.
3. A further problems presents itself when I deploy:

The deploy script basically moves the current production code to another directory and puts in its place the updated code. When it's restarted I would expect the 'run.rb' script to recreate the 'var' folder in 'background' (as per line 24), however the daemons gem errors out with the following:

```
Starting Daemon...
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/pidfile.rb:94:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /var/www/main/projects/systems/background/var/background_jobs.pid (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/pidfile.rb:94:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/pidfile.rb:94:in `pid='
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:254:in `start_proc'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:294:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:193
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `catch_exceptions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'
    from run.rb:19
```

Now I can fix this simply by creating the 'var' folder in the terminal and running it again, so in case you're wondering why I'm bothering you folks, I'm sure some of you will appreciate that this is a problem that I don't want to simply hack. I want to work out what happened here, and try to get back to what I had before!

Comment: You could move `FileUtils.mkdir_p('var')` before `Daemons.run_proc`

Comment: that makes sense to me. but why did this code work before?

Comment: Something else must've been creating the folder

Comment: if that is the case, then why the FileUtils.mkdir_p('var')? This has always worked in the past